# Multiple foreach getting the first array empty

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter.
What I am doing is, I am getting all the records from the table and I am passing the id to the model to get all the related records. So in the view page, I am displaying all users `Name` and `Email` using the first foreach and in the second foreach I am displaying all the records related to the id.

So my output is,

```
Name: alex
Email: alex@gmail.com

Active Name:poiuy
Active Duration: 3m

Active Name:wer
Active Duration: 6m

Active Name:pojfd
Active Duration: 12m
```

**Controller**

```
$getDetails['secMember']=$this->Member_model->getSecMemberinfo();//getting all the member details

$getDetails['getSecMemberActivity']=$this->Member_model->getSecMemberActivity($getDetails['secMember']->id);//getting all the details related to the id

$this->load->view('profile',$getDetails);
```

**Model**

```
public function getSecMemberinfo(){
        $get_s_member = array('members.member_type' =>2,'members.is_Approved'=>1,'members.is_status'=>1);
        $res =$this->db->where($get_s_member);
                       ->from('members'); 
                       ->join('relation_member', 'relation_member.secondary_member_id = members.member_id');
                       ->join('relations', 'relations.relations_id = relation_member.relation_with_primary_member'); 
                       ->get();
                       ->result();

     return $res;

    }

    public function getSecMemberActivity($gotSecondaryMemberId){
        $getDetails = array('members.member_id'=>$gotSecondaryMemberId);
        $result = $this->db->where($getDetails)
                              ->from('members')
                              ->join('member_activity', 'members.member_id = member_activity.member_id','LEFT')
                              ->join('activity_name', 'activity_name.activity_name_id = member_activity.activity_id','LEFT')
                              ->get()
                              ->result();
        if($result)
        {
           return $result;  
        }
        else 
        {
           return 0;    
        }

    }
```

**view**

```
<?php 
 foreach ($secMember as $secPay) {//first foreach
   if($secPay->member_type == 2){?>
    <div class="perSet">
      <h2><?php echo $secPay->name?></h2>
      <h2><?php echo $secPay->email?></h2>
    <?php 
    $SActivity=$getSecMemberActivity;
    if ($SActivity){
     foreach ($SActivity as $sec_activities) {?> <!--2nd foreach-->
      <div><p><?php echo $sec_activities->activeName;?></p></div>
      <div><p><?php echo $sec_activities->activeDuration;?></p></div>
    <?php }}?>
</div>
<?php }}?>
```

I have two for each.`foreach ($SActivity as $sec_activities)` I am getting the multiple records but in the first array I am getting the empty records then I am getting my output.

for example: I have two records in the `$sec_activities`. so I am getting the output like

```
stdClass Object
(   [id] =>
    [activeName] => 
    [activeDuration] => 
)
stdClass Object
(   [id] =>1
    [activeName] => qwer
    [activeDuration] => 6m
)
stdClass Object
(   [id] =>
    [activeName] => 
    [activeDuration] => 
)
stdClass Object
(   [id] =>2
    [activeName] => lkjh
    [activeDuration] => 3m
)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.  Do you intend for the 'foreach'es to be nested?  How is $getSecMemberActivity set?  why iterate for each secpay?

Comment: @anmari, I will explain you in details. wait

Comment: @anmari, I updated my question. Please check it. Let me know if you want more explanation

Comment: may I know the `getSecMemberActivity()` method inside the `Member_model` model?

Comment: @HastaDhana, Yes, I have one model called as Member_model and there are two functions called as getSecMemberinfo() and getSecMemberActivity()

Comment: before the first foreach, could you do `die($getSecMemberActivity);`? And what is the output?

Comment: @HastaDhana, Wait let me try this. Also I am updating the model code

Comment: @HastaDhana, I tried and I am getting "Message: Array to string conversion" and my second for each not displaying anything. but I am getting the records of first for each

Comment: Try `die(json_encode($getSecMemberActivity));`, what is the output?

Comment: I have 1,2,3,4,5 records and 1-3 I have recorded in the first model and in second model 4-5 I have records in the first model but don't have records in the second model. I think that the reason I am getting the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185958/discussion-between-user9437856-and-hasta-dhana).